# Deleting rows with Python in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

All I would like to do is delete a row if it has a value of '0' in the third column. An example of the data would be something like:

```
6.5, 5.4, 0, 320
6.5, 5.4, 1, 320
```

So the first row would need to be deleted whereas the second would stay.

What I have so far is as follows:

```
import csv
input = open('first.csv', 'rb')
output = open('first_edit.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(output)
for row in csv.reader(input):
    if row[2]!=0:
        writer.writerow(row)
input.close()
output.close()
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You are very close; currently you compare the `row[2]` with integer `0`, make the comparison with the string `"0"`. When you read the data from a file, it is a string and not an integer, so that is why your integer check fails currently:

```
row[2]!="0":
```

Also, you can use the `with` keyword to make the current code slightly more pythonic so that the lines in your code are reduced and you can omit the `.close` statements:

```
import csv
with open('first.csv', 'rb') as inp, open('first_edit.csv', 'wb') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for row in csv.reader(inp):
        if row[2] != "0":
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Note that `input` is a Python builtin, so I've used another variable name instead.

---

***Edit***: The values in your csv file's rows are comma *and* space separated; In a normal csv, they would be simply comma separated and a check against `"0"` would work, so you can either use `strip(row[2]) != 0`, or check against `" 0"`.

The better solution would be to correct the csv format, but in case you want to persist with the current one, the following will work with your given csv file format:

```
$ cat test.py 
import csv
with open('first.csv', 'rb') as inp, open('first_edit.csv', 'wb') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for row in csv.reader(inp):
        if row[2] != " 0":
            writer.writerow(row)
$ cat first.csv 
6.5, 5.4, 0, 320
6.5, 5.4, 1, 320
$ python test.py 
$ cat first_edit.csv 
6.5, 5.4, 1, 320
```

Comment: I have tried that as well, but it does not seem to be working regardless if it is set as a string or integer

Comment: I tried the way you edited it, and I have also tried to do a strip(), but the output file still has the rows with '0' values!

Comment: I have ran it a few times, and it comes back the same.

Comment: @WillB I'm not sure what you are running then, I've already posted the inputs and code I'm using. Maybe, you should use a `pdb.set_trace()` statement within your for loop to identify why it is not working.

Comment: i converted my csv into a .txt to see that it was reading it as "  00.0000", which was the only way to make it work. Thanks for helping me solve the problem!

Comment: is there any way to do this without having to create and write to an additional file??

Comment: @BugWhisperer yes, there should be. But OP wants to do it with an additional file.

Comment: ok, ive had trouble locating anything on doing this within a single file. would u be able to possibly provide me with a link to any post/info regarding this?

Answer (score 4):

Use `pandas` amazing library:

The solution to the question:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv(file)
df =  df[df.name != "dog"] 

# df.column_name != whole string from the cell
# now, all the rows with the column: Name and Value: "dog" will be deleted

df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

**General solution:**

Use this function:

```
def remove_specific_row_from_csv(file, column_name, *args):
    '''
    :param file: file to remove the rows from
    :param column_name: The column that determines which row will be 
           deleted (e.g. if Column == Name and row-*args
           contains "Gavri", All rows that contain this word will be deleted)
    :param args: Strings from the rows according to the conditions with 
                 the column
    '''
    row_to_remove = []
    for row_name in args:
        row_to_remove.append(row_name)
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        for row in row_to_remove:
            df = df[eval("df.{}".format(column_name)) != row]
        df.to_csv(file, index=False)
    except Exception  as e:
        raise Exception("Error message....")
```

Function implementation:

```
remove_specific_row_from_csv(file_name, "column_name", "dog_for_example", "cat_for_example")
```

**Note:** In this function, you can send unlimited cells of strings and all these rows will be deleted (assuming they exist in the single-column sent).

Comment: One-line summary: use a Numpy-style filtering: `df = df[df.my_column != value]`

Comment: @Basj, you're right but pls do not forget the added value when things are arranged as a clear function and the possibility of sending unlimited cells of strings

Answer (score 1):

You should have `if row[2] != "0"`.  Otherwise it's not checking to see if the string value is equal to 0.

Comment: Yes, I did try that too earlier, but it did not seem to work either!

Comment: Yes, I am looking at the output file

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to deleting row in csv:

```
import csv

with open("employees.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    rows_keep = [row for row in reader if row[0] != "11111111"]


with open("employees.csv", "w", newline="") as wrt:
    writer = csv.writer(wrt)
    for row in rows_keep:
        writer.writerow(row)
```