# How can I remove a row from csv file with python where a value of any column is missing

Tags: python, csv

How can I use the csv module to remove all rows where any of the column values is missing? I my case I have two columns a and b, so if I have a value on a but nothing on b, that row should be removed. How an I achieve this?

Comment: This is far too vague/broad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting rows with Python in a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725932/deleting-rows-with-python-in-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
with open(in_filename) as infile:
    with open(out_filename, 'w') as outfile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        writer.writerows(filter(all, reader))
```