# Remove rows from CSV file containing certain characters

Tags: python, string, csv, row

I am looking to remove rows from a csv file if they contain specific strings or in their row.

I'd like to be able to create a new output file versus overwriting the original.

I need to remove any rows that contain "py-board" or "coffee"

Example Input:

```
173.20.1.1,2-base
174.28.2.2,2-game
174.27.3.109,xyz-b13-coffee-2
174.28.32.8,2-play
175.31.4.4,xyz-102-o1-py-board
176.32.3.129,xyz-b2-coffee-1
177.18.2.8,six-jump-walk
```

Expected Output:

```
173.20.1.1,2-base
174.28.2.2,2-game
174.28.32.8,2-play
177.18.2.8,six-jump-walk
```

I tried this
[Deleting rows with Python in a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725932/deleting-rows-with-python-in-a-csv-file)

```
import csv
with open('input_csv_file.csv', 'rb') as inp, open('purged_csv_file', 'wb') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for row in csv.reader(inp):
        if row[1] != "py-board" or if row[1] != "coffee":
            writer.writerow(row)
```

and I tried this

```
import csv
with open('input_csv_file.csv', 'rb') as inp, open('purged_csv_file', 'wb') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for row in csv.reader(inp):
        if row[1] != "py-board":
            if row[1] != "coffee":
                writer.writerow(row)
```

and this

```
        if row[1][-8:] != "py-board":
            if row[1][-8:] != "coffee-1":
                if row[1][-8:] != "coffee-2":
```

but got this error

```
  File "C:\testing\syslogyamlclean.py", line 6, in <module>
    for row in csv.reader(inp):
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

Comment: This is wrong: `if row[1] != "py-board" or if row[1] != "coffee" ` What about this:  `if (row[1] != "py-board" or row[1] != "coffee"): `  ?

Comment: `"xyz-102-o1-py-board" != "py-board"` However, `"py-board" in "xyz-102-o1-py-board"` is `True`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp - I also tried if row[1][-8:] != "py-board":

Comment: Also, you are opening the file in binary mode (the "b" in "rb") but the csv library wants text. Change "rb" to "r".

Comment: @JohnnyMopp - changed rb to r and still got this:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually not use the `csv` package for this goal. This can be achieved easily using standard file reading and writing.

Try this code (I have written some comments to make it self-explanatory):

```
# We open the source file and get its lines
with open('input_csv_file.csv', 'r') as inp:
    lines = inp.readlines()

# We open the target file in write-mode
with open('purged_csv_file.csv', 'w') as out:
    # We go line by line writing in the target file
    # if the original line does not include the
    # strings 'py-board' or 'coffee'
    for line in lines:
        if not 'py-board' in line and not 'coffee' in line:
            out.write(line)
```

Comment: I tried this, but it did not remove the rows with those strings, they are still in the purged file.

Comment: That's strange, I executed it and the output file contains only the rows you wanted. Did you literally copy/pasted and tested it @PythonDawg?

Comment: actually, yes, that worked, thank you so much! sorry, when I copied, I forgot to change the sample strings to actually match the ones I needed to remove. Thank you!

Comment: What if I constantly need to remove string, the for loop writing is very time-consuming

Comment: @myworldbox, I do not really get your point. How would you do it in a less time-consuming way, then?

Answer (score 0):

```
# pandas helps to read and manipulate .csv file
import pandas as pd

# read .csv file
df = pd.read_csv('input_csv_file.csv', sep=',', header=None)
df
              0                    1
0    173.20.1.1               2-base
1    174.28.2.2               2-game
2  174.27.3.109     xyz-b13-coffee-2
3   174.28.32.8               2-play
4    175.31.4.4  xyz-102-o1-py-board
5  176.32.3.129      xyz-b2-coffee-1
6    177.18.2.8        six-jump-walk

# filter rows
result = df[np.logical_not(df[1].str.contains('py-board') | df[1].str.contains('coffee'))]
print(result)
             0              1
0   173.20.1.1         2-base
1   174.28.2.2         2-game
3  174.28.32.8         2-play
6   177.18.2.8  six-jump-walk

# save to result.csv file
result.to_csv('result.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: thanks. I was trying to solve without pandas if I could and also, I want the output to exclude those items versus include. Hard to tell from your example if that's happening.